# Combine [vi] and [vim] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We should combine the [vi] and the [vim] tags.

From the [vi] tag wiki:

> Questions about the text editor "vi" or "vim"

I am not sure whether to keep the [vi] tag or the [vim] tag, but I don't think there is a reason to keep two separate tags.

Comment: You mean, create a [tag synonym](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vi` and `vim` are two [different applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418396/what-is-the-difference-between-vi-and-vim) that share the same name.

By default, Ubuntu ships with `vim-tiny`, which does not have the same full feature set of true `vim`.

The tags are similar, yes, but they are not synonyms. Questions about `vi` very much do apply to `vim` as well, but questions about `vim` do not apply to `vi`.